# The name 'NHibernateUtil' does not exist in the current context

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-projections

Below projection query throws " The name 'NHibernateUtil' does not exist in the current context" error when I try to run the app. I tried including namespace NHibernate.Util but it still wont work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 template.Criteria.SetProjection(
                Projections.ProjectionList()
                .Add(Projections.GroupProperty(Projections.SqlFunction("date",NHibernateUtil.Date,Projections.GroupProperty("IssueDateTime")))
, "DateVal")
                .Add(Projections.Sum("TotalFare"), "TotalFare")
            );
```

Comment: Sounds like a missing reference.

Comment: Yes, But I am not sure what is missing. Do I have to install any sql dialects for this to run properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NHibernateUtil` class is in the `NHibernate` namespace, not `NHibernate.Util`